# sequences with a fractal dimension

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, fractals, integer-sequences

This is inspired by the self-similarity of the celebrated [Golay-Rudin-Shapiro sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudin-Shapiro_sequence), more exactly, of its alternating partial sums. (This latter one is [oeis 020990](http://oeis.org/A020990)). The pictures show the 550 first terms, then the 9000 first terms.

[image: 550]
[image: 9000]

It makes sense to define a certain fractal $F$ as the "limit" of the graph $\Gamma=\{(n,a_n)\}_{n\ge0}$.
More precisely:
Fix a rectangle $R\subset\mathbb R^2$, e.g. the unit square. Take the part $\Gamma_k$ of $\Gamma$ between $n=2^{2k-1}$ and $n=2^{2k+1}-1$ and rescale it to a graph $\Gamma^0_k$ that fits $R$ best.
Then because of the geometrical (almost-) similarity of the $\Gamma^0_k$,  the limit $F:=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\Gamma^0_k\subset\mathbb R^2$ is well-defined. Note that its Hausdorff dimension is $d=3/2$.

Other examples:

- the sequence [oeis 004074](http://oeis.org/A004074/graph) that defines likewise the [Blancmange curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blancmange_curve), dimension $d=1$
- sequences linked to the Gray code, like [003188](http://oeis.org/A003188/graph) or [006068](http://oeis.org/A006068/graph), both with $d=1$
- [Stern's diatomic series](http://oeis.org/A002487/graph) (a.k.a. Stern-Brocot sequence or [$fusc$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin-Wilf_tree#Stern's_diatomic_sequence)) yields a fractal with dimension $d=\frac{\ln 3}{\ln 2}$
- it makes sense to relate (if not to *identify*) the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) with the sequence $1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,... $ where $a_n=1$ iff the ternary representation of $n$ has only 0's and 2's (equivalently, the cellular automaton where at each step $1 \mapsto 101$ and $0 \mapsto000$), and to say this sequence has dimension $\frac{\ln2}{\ln3}$. Likewise for the "fat Cantor set" iterating 11100111 (dimension $\frac{\ln5}{\ln8}$) and all other sorts of Cantor dust.
- the [devil's staircase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), obtained by "integrating" the Cantor set, corresponds to [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A081611/graph), and a "mirrored" version of it can be found [here.](http://oeis.org/A005836/graph)
- Other sequences of [Toothpick and Cellular Automata type](http://oeis.org/wiki/Catalog_of_Toothpick_and_CA_Sequences_in_OEIS)

Like for most other sequences of this kind, the ressemblance is best seen when looking at a range from either $1$ to $2^n$, or (for some, like the Blancmange curve) from $2^{n-1}$ to $2^n$.

Note that it is not at all straightforward or even possible to define a fractal for every self-similar integer sequence $a=(a_n)_{n\ge0}$ (self-similar meaning as usual that there is a $k\ge2$ and $\lambda$ such that $a_n=\lambda a_{kn}$). On the other hand, there are also sequences with a fractal-like appearance without being self-similar in the above sense.

Question:

> - ***Has the idea of the "fractal dimension" of certain sequences been investigated before?***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interestingly, fractal dimensions of the human DNA sequence have been analyzed and different embeddings considered: http://biocomplexity.indiana.edu/jglazier/docs/papers/20_DNA_Analysis.pdf.

Comment: "...indicating the presence of signiﬁcant information content in DNA sequences not explained by base or dimer frequencies". Interesting indeed!

Answer (score 3):

Taking a truncated integer sequence is essentially the same as defining the "heights" of the line endpoints of a 2-dimensional curve, similar to http://www.gameprogrammer.com/fractal.html
my guess is that this is not really new, but rather a cumbersome way to define self-similar curves.

Making a reasonable scaling will in some examples, as above, give a well-defined limit curve.
Maybe it is possible to compute the Hausdorff dimension by doing a discrete Fourier transform
of the sequence. The spectrum should be quite interesting, I think.