# On the first sequence without triple in arithmetic progression

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, ds.dynamical-systems, sequences-and-series, oeis

In [this Numberphile video](https://youtu.be/o8c4uYnnNnc?t=216) (from 3:36 to 7:41), Neil Sloane explains an amazing sequence:

It is the lexicographically first among the sequences of positive integers without triple in arithmetic progression (i.e.,  such that for any two distinct points in the graph, there is no point in their middle, as for $a_n=n^2$ or $b_n = 2^n$). It is due to Jack W. Grahl (2013): [A229037](http://oeis.org/A229037).
$$1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 8, 5, 5, 9, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, \dots$$    Its graph is surprising:

[image]
[image]
The following colored plot of 16 million terms is due to [reddit user garnet420](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/40stfx/followup_pretty_plots_of_a22903_the_fun_sequence/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) (horizontal divisions are 1000000; vertical divisions are 25000).

[image]

This sequence reveals many possible questions (like the existence of a convergent pattern, a fractal structure)). The following one is [due to Charles R. Greathouse](http://list.seqfan.eu/pipermail/seqfan/2014-January/012322.html) (and deserves to be posted here):

**Question**: Does the term $1$ appear infinitely many times in this sequence?

*Remark*: the first numbers $n$ for which the $n^{th}$ term is $1$ are given by [A236246](http://oeis.org/A236246).
$$1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 13, 14, 28, 29, 31, 32, 37, 38, 40, 41, 82, 83, 85, 86, 92, 93, 96, 105, \dots$$
[image]

In addition, we observe that the succession $1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4$ appears several times, so we could also ask whether it appears infinitely many times.

Finally, we can create variations of the first sequence, replacing triple by $r$-tuple for a fixed $r \ge 3$, and ask the same questions.

---

Let us consider the variation suggested by Richard Stanley in comment where we only exclude *weakly increasing* arithmetic progressions. The first terms are the same up to the $54^{th}$ term.
For the former sequence, the $20$ next terms are
$$ 9, 4, 4, 5, 5, 10, 5, 5, 10, 2, 10, 13, 11, 10, 8, 11, 13, 10, 12, 10, 10 $$
whereas for the variation they are
$$ 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 10, 5, 5, 10, 10, 11, 13, 10, 11, 10, 11, 13, 10, 10, 12, 13 $$
It is *now* available on OEIS at [A309890](https://oeis.org/A309890). [Listen it played with a marimba](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sSkrVcKM-Ru0X_IPNvAZF7AnNSB8a0be), it's incredibly pleasant!

Its graph is completely different, but also amazing:

[image]
[image]

Finally the numbers $n$ for which the $n^{th}$ term is $1$ are given by [A003278](https://oeis.org/A003278) (see Richard's comment).
[image]

---

A SageMath code computing the variation:

```
# %attach SAGE/ThreeFree.spyx

from sage.all import *

cpdef ThreeFree(int n):
    cdef int i,j,k,s,Li,Lj
    cdef list L,Lb
    cdef set b
    L=[1,1]
    for k in range(2,n):
        b=set()
        for i in range(k):
            if 2*((i+k)/2)==i+k:
                j=(i+k)/2
                Li,Lj=L[i],L[j]
                s=2*Lj-Li
                if s>0 and Li<=Lj: # this second assumption provides the variation
                    b.add(s)
        if 1 not in b:
            L.append(1)
        else:
            Lb=list(b)
            Lb.sort()
            for t in Lb:
                if t+1 not in b:
                    L.append(t+1)
                    break 
    return L
```

For having the graph, do `points([(i+1,L[i]) for i in range(n)],size=1,alpha=0.04,dpi=1000)`

Comment: If we modify the definition so that we only exclude *weakly
increasing* arithmetic progressions, i.e., $a(j),a(j+k),a(j+2k)$ are in
arithmetic progression (with $k\geq 1$) and $a(j)\leq a(j+k)\leq
a(j+2k)$, then it is easy to see that terms equal to 1 are indexed by
http://oeis.org/A236246. This suggests looking some more at this
modified sequence. Could it coincide with the original sequence? I
haven't tried to check this experimentally.

Comment: @RichardStanley Let $a$ be the former sequence, let $b$ be the modified one, and assume that the terms indexed by $1$ are unchanged. Observe that $a(27) = 9$ and $a(59) = 5$, but there is no $i \ge 0$ and $k>0$ such that $a(i)=a(i+k)=1$ and $i+2k = 59+59-27 = 91$, so $b(91) = 1$, but $a(91)=2$, contradiction.

Comment: Oops, I foolishly assumed that A236246 was actually https://oeis.org/A003278 without checking. It is clear that the indices for which $b(n)=1$ coincide with A003278. Perhaps it would be interesting to consider $b(n)$ for its own sake.

Comment: I wonder if for the question whether every natural occurs at all in this sequence, even though it seems intuitively clear, it is easier to prove that the answer is positive.

Comment: A better visualization (see [this question](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/47573/how-to-plot-points-of-size-less-than-1/) on ask.sagemath.org, especially the last comments) shows that the "empty" regions are not empty, but simply too sparse to get a visible representation on the rendered graph.

Comment: It seems to me that the sequence in which we exclude only weakly increasing progressions contains infinitely many 1's. Indeed, if we assume that the last 1 occurs at position N, it easy to check that we can set also the 2N position to be equal to 1, a contradiction. Similarly, we can show that there are infinitely many 2's.

Comment: @Capublanca: Yes and Ralf Stephan provides a formula for this sequence in the webpage [A003278](https://oeis.org/A003278). It would be great to deduce from that the infinity for the first sequence.

Comment: I could not possibly understand how the sequence is defined from the above description. But OEIS defines it clearly and tersely as the lexicographically first sequence {a(n)} of positive integers such that for all positive n and k, a(n+k) - a(n) ≠ a(n+2k) - a(n+k).