# Further unexpected behavior involving not √2 and parity

Tags: nt.number-theory

Starting with the fascinating question of Sebastien Palcoux [Unexpected behavior involving √2 and parity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353493/unexpected-behavior-involving-%e2%88%9a2-and-parity) 
let now $\alpha \not= \sqrt 2$ and consider the map

$$f: n \mapsto \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
         \left \lfloor{n/\alpha} \right \rfloor \text{ if } n \text{ even,}  \\
         \left \lfloor{n \cdot \alpha} \right \rfloor \text{ if } n \text{ odd.}
    \end{array}
\right.$$
As in the question of Palcoux let $f^{k+1} := f \circ f^k$ and consider the sequence $(f^k(73) \colon k \in \mathbb{N})$. As noted in the comments to Palcoux questions the sequence with $\alpha = \sqrt 2$ does not seem to be bounded.
I tried some randomly chosen $\alpha = \sqrt {1.9}, \sqrt 3, \sqrt {2.1}, \ldots$. In all these cases the sequence was bounded and ended sometimes with $1$.

Is there any reason why the case $\alpha = \sqrt 2$ is so special?

Comment: Thanks! You should have a look to my previous post: https://mathoverflow.net/q/353434/34538 which asks this question in general, and to my next one: https://mathoverflow.net/q/353524/34538 showing that such unboundedness happens (and is proved by Lucia in comment) with the golden ratio (and a family of quadratic algebraic integers), but much more strongly. What is mysterious with √2 is that it provides something intermediate.